# Como adicionar um texto a um input via javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero inserir um texto nos 2 inputs da imagem mas somente via javascript com manipulação de DOM.
Como faço isso?

Comment: Olha ai meu querido fiz pra vc https://prnt.sc/t9amv3 com JS não da para colocar um texto dentro de uma imagem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas caso tenha entendido.

Primeiro você captura o input que quer no javascript, algo como:

`const ipt = document.getElementById('id_do_input');`

e posteriormente muda a propriedade value dele.

`ipt.value = 'teste';`